# Averaging multiple .nc files - NCO operators on Linux

Tags: linux, netcdf, nco

I have a folder with 60+ netCDF (*.nc) files. I need to find an average over all 60+ datafiles but I am running into errors in my terminal.

Therefore, I just need to know how to average all 60+ files and have the result saved in an `output.nc` file ( I know how to do that with 2 or 3 files at a time, but is there a way to do all 60+?)

Here is what I tried : `'ncra data_ncfiles/* dataaverage.nc` --> the `*` should tell Linux that ALL 60 files in the folder to average.

The error I get is: `ncra: ERROR nco_sng_sntz() reports character '' from unsanitized user-input string "CbPM_ncfiles/" is not on whitelist of acceptable characters. For security purposes NCO restricts the set of characters appearing in user input, including filenames, to: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_-.@ :%/". NB: This restriction was first imposed in NCO 4.7.3 (February, 2018), and may cause breakage of older workflows. Please contact NCO if you have a real-world use-case that shows why the character '*' should be white-listed. HINT: Re-try command after replacing transgressing characters with innocuous characters.`

I also tried without the asterisk an it didnt work

UPDATE: I tried it again:

`ncra data_ncfiles/* dataaverage.nc`

and got this error:

`ncra: ERROR no variables fit criteria for processing ncra: HINT Extraction list must contain at least one record variable that is not NC_CHAR or NC_STRING. A record variable is a variable defined with a record dimension. Often the record dimension, aka unlimited dimension, refers to time. To change an existing dimension from a fixed to a record dimensions see http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#mk_rec_dmn or to add a new record dimension to all variables see http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncecat_rnm`

Answer (score 1):

This command

```
ncra data_ncfiles/* dataaverage.nc
```

relies on shell-globbing to expand the filename list. It will work if `ls data_ncfiles/*` gives the expected list of files from the same directory. Your post is unclear, but you may have turned-off globbing by using quotes.

The next error, `ERROR no variables fit criteria for processing`, usually occurs when your input lacks the record dimension. And the awesome error points exactly to instructions on how to workaround the problem. Follow those instructions.